# Insert values to a table from another table based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, create-table

So I have a SQL table in which I am entering values by joining other columns and entering the column values from that table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_t (id INT, cname NVARCHAR(100), val INT, aid INT)
INSERT INTO #temp_t 
SELECT DISTINCT
ISNULL(IDXC.id, 0) id, sg.name + '-webApp' cName, 0 val, ag.ID aid
FROM spgroup sg
JOIN APPA APP ON sg.id > 1 AND sg.val & 4 = 0 AND APP.dagi = sg.id 
JOIN AIDBI XDI ON APP.bs = XDI.bsid
LEFT JOIN #IDXC ON IDXC.agpv = sg.id
WHERE IDXC.id IS NULL
```

Now while inserting values to the table I need to check if sg.name exists in `sysName` table if yes then `-webApp` needs to be replaced by `-andApp` otherwise it remains `-webApp`

How can I do the same?

Comment: Why do all of your references to tables (apart from the temporary one) have the `NOLOCK` hint? You do understand what it does, correct? You *are* therefore happy with possibly wrong, and inconsitant, results?

Comment: @Larnu Please ignore that, edited

Comment: Notice how the table / alias IDXC does not exist in your query and will generate an error. Guess that is your temp table? But your logic makes no sense. This column expression `ISNULL(IDXC.id, 0)` appears pointless when you specifically filter for those NULL values. Why use that column in the expression when it seems you should use sg.id (which will not - presumably - be null in your resultset). Using DISTINCT is also a bad smell and suggests either a schema problem or a logical flaw in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` in a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(i.id, 0) as id,
       (sg.name +
        (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysname sn WHERE sn.name = sg.name)
              THEN '-andApp' ELSE '-webApp'
         END)
       )  as cName,
       0 as val, ag.ID as aid
FROM spgroup sg JOIN
      APPA APP 
      ON sg.id > 1 AND (sg.val & 4) = 0 AND APP.dagi = sg.id  JOIN
      AIDBI XDI 
      ON APP.bs = XDI.bsid LEFT JOIN
      #IDXC i
      ON i.IDXCsgpv = sg.id
WHERE i.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Why COALESCE? any specific reason

Comment: @FarhanAhmed . . . It is the SQL standard function that replaces `NULL` values.  I prefer SQL standard functions unless there is a good reason to use bespoke functions.